# A collection of custom structures (a wrapper) with a single member (also a custom structure), to a collection of the single members

Tags: c++, c++11, wrapper

The problem is specific but the solution open ended. I'm a lone coder looking to bat some ideas around with some fellow programmers.

I have a wrapper for a maths library. The wrapper provides the system with a consistent interface, while allowing me to switch in/out math libraries for different platforms. The wrapper contains a single member, so say for my Matrix4x4 wrapper class there is an api_matrix_4x4 structure as the only member to the wrapper.

My current target platform has a nifty little optimised library, with a few of those nifty functions requiring a C-style array of the wrapper's embedded member, while my wrapper functions for those math API functions don't want to expose that member type to the rest of the system. So we have a collection of wrappers (reference/pointer to) going into the function, & the members of the wappers being needed in a collection inside the function, so they can be passed to the math API.

I'm predominantly using C++, including C++11 features, & can also go C-style. Ideally I want a no-exception solution, & to avoid as many, if not all dynamic allocations. My wrapper functions can use standard library arrays or vectors, or C-style pointers to arrays as parameters, & whatever is necessary internally, just no dynamic casting (Run-Time Type Information).

1) Can I cast a custom struct/class containing a single custom struct, to the custom struct? If so, what about if it was a standard library collection of them. I'm thinking about type slicing here.

2) Would you perhaps use a template to mask the type passed to the function, although the implementation can only act on a single type (based on the math API used), or is such usage of templates considered bad?

3) Can you think of a nifty solution, perhaps involving swaps/move semantics/emplacement? If so, please help by telling me about it.

4) Or am I resigned to the obvious, iterate through one collection, taking the member out into another, then using that for the API function?

Example of what I am doing by the wrapper struct & wrapper function signature, & example of what I am trying to avoid doing is given by the function implementation:

```
struct Vector3dWrapper
{
   API_Specific_Vector_3d m_api_vector_3d;

   inline void operation_needing_vector_3d_wrappers(std::vector<Vector3d>& vectors)
   {
      // Now need a collection of API_Specific_Vector_3ds 
      try
      {
         std::Vector<API_Specific_Vector_3d> api_vectors;
         api_vectors.reserve(vectors.size());
         for( auto vectors_itr = vectors.begin(); vectors_itr != vectors.end(); ++vectors)
         {
            // fill each Vector3d.m_api_vector_3d into api_vectors
         }
      }
      catch(std::bad_alloc &e)
      {
         // handle... though in reality, try/catch is done elsewhere in the system.
      }



      // Signature is API_Multiply_Vectors_With_Matrix_And_Project(API_Specific_Vector_3d* vectors, size_t vector_count)
      API_Multiply_Vectors_With_Matrix_And_Project(&api_vectors, api_vectors.size());
   }

};
```

Comment: That question covers rather a wide range of topics. Could you be more specific, with some examples?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can cast a standard-layout struct (such as a struct compatible with C) to its first member, but what's the point? Just access the first member and apply `&`.
2. Templates usually allow uniform parameterization over a set of types. You can write a template that's only instantiated once, but again that seems pointless. What you really want is a different interface library for each platform. Perhaps templates could help define common code shared between them. Or you could do the same in plain C by setting `typedef`s before `#include`.
3. Solution to what? The default copy and move semantics should work for flat, C-style structs containing numbers. As for deep copies, if the underlying libraries have pointer-based structures, you need to be careful and implement all the semantics you'll need. Safe… simple… default… "nifty" sounds dirty.
4. Not sure I understand what you're doing with collections. You mean that every function requires its parameters to be first inserted into a generic container object?  Constructing containers sounds expensive. Your functions should parallel the functions in the underlying libraries as well as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. 1 is useful to know. I figured 2 would allow me that uniform parameterisation, but you are right re the single instantiation, which makes it little more than a mask, which is perhaps ok for what I need. For 3 I know they work for flat C-style structs, & no need for deep copies as no pointers relating to the member. Re 4, it is only 2 functions from 25-odd functions that the math API needs a collection of it's types that I am wrapping to be passed into. I just don't want to expose those types externally from the wrapper.

Comment: For 3, I guess I was looking for "clever & efficient" container + type conversion idioms/tricks, albeit safety would be a concern. Perhaps, off the top of my head, something like iterating through the wrapper container parameter & cast + emplace into a function-local wrapper-member container. Just ideas really. Math code needs to be relatively efficient, otherwise I may end up wasting what optimisations (SIMD instructions, neon, etc.) the API offers by doing my wrapper type collection to API type collection conversion...

Comment: @codey If the platforms potentially have some fancy optimizations such as vectorization, you need to be very careful to avoid casts that could scare away the optimizer. Really, the compiler likes you to do things the straightforward and semantic way. If your library could consist of a few typedefs and one-liner inline functions, you should do that. If no underlying function takes a container type, and the user doesn't need them, why even consider the additional cost and effort?

Comment: Thanks again. I started out the typdef way, but had some data carrier types from my system that I wanted to interact with the math types. Also the math API I'm work on currently was straight C, involving calling, say, Matrix functions having to pass a matrix in & receive a new one back, etc. After a while I switched to an object style, that a matrix could retain values, be assigned to directly, or call non-member functions in the same namespace that did what the library did. Ultimately, although a little more typing than a few typedefs & inliners, it's gives a more flexibility & integration.

Comment: I'm going to play around with a few solutions, but think what with C++11 features mentioned, &/or the ability to cast a struct to its one & only internal member, what I'm trying to do could be achieved with little more than a extra instructions. The templated function approach (which would be only one or 2 in the wrapper interface) is still a consideration. I guess I was looking for recommendations. Thank you for yours.